# iPhone Game - Sprites

Tags: game-design, iphone, sprites

I have made games with cocos2d for the iphone however I am looking to move on from that, is there a good direction you could suggest? If not I was planning on using what the SDK gives me, and so for example to make a sprite, say the player on screen, rather than a CCSprite, what would be best to use? What do I need to go and learn?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with cocos2d?

Comment: I agree with bummzack.  Unless you have some requirements that cocos2d can't fulfill, or you want to learn more about how 3D graphics are done on the iPhone, I'd stick with cocos2d and its simpler API.

Answer (score 3):

cocos2d is using OpenGL ES as its rendering engine, so if you wish to move on, OpenGL ES is the next step.